# How to read transaction memo from a qr code?

Tags: ethereum, qr-code, cryptocurrency

I was wondering how to create a qr code that contains wallet address, amount and memo.

I have found that you can get amount, message and label on query string:
`ethereum:_wallet_address?amount=20&message=test`

so what about the memo? I tried `&memo=test` but didn't work.

Can anyone help??

Comment: Ethereum doesn't support `memo`, while some other networks do. What goal you're aiming to achieve with the memo?

Comment: @PetrHejda actually it is on usdt. It is for a crypto payment which I show a qrcode to user. at first I just used wallet address but to make it more convenient I want the wallet, amount and memo field be filled on scan (and I know some wallets dont support it)